# svn:needs-lock Files need lock, but I cannot find the property

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I'm a little confused with something that is happening in our SVN. In my local checkout, some of the files seem to be set as "needs-lock" but I cannot find the corresponding property.

- Most files in the checkout don't need a lock, only some
- The files requiring a lock do not have a needs-lock property
- There does not seem to be a needs-lock property on any of the
  containing directories
- Both tortiseSVN and Eclipse (though Subclipse) recognise which files
  require a lock.

Can anyone suggest where the property/information is being stored for these files?

Comment: svn pl on one of these files only reports a property "svn:mime-type" (they are word documents). svn pl on the directory reports no properties.

Comment: Well then. Do `svn propedit` on the files/directories you wish to modify. I don't know why they don't have the properties, but set them and if they change again in the future we'll dig deeper.

Comment: Unfortunately, needs-lock can only be turned off by removing the property. However, I did find out what was causing this (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for the information of others:

After a lot of mucking around, it looks like setting a file to read-only (in windows) is enough for Tortise SVN and Eclipse to show the grey needs-lock icon (in Package Explorer or Navigator for Eclipse, Windows Explorer for Tortise SVN).

So it seems that the grey icon means that the file is under source control and the file is read-only, regardless of the 'needs-lock' property.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA it might be worth checking that you haven't locked the file in the source editor by clicking on the lock icon.

The lock icon is a toggle button located at the bottom right of the IDE. If you hover over it shows the "Click to toggle the read-only attribute" text tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a second to figure this out.

How to toggle on/off the 'Needs-Lock'property for SVN files.

(Using Windows Explorer)

Go to file(s) you want to put lock on/take lock off

Right click > Tortoise SVN > Properties

Click New button > select **Needs-Lock**

Select **Locking required (read-only update)** radio button or **No locking required** radio button > OK